# Apply CSS style to the first element of type when already using :nth-child

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

In the following example I would like to not apply any background color to the cell `Not here...`.

In other words, I would like to apply my CSS `.class tag:modifer` only for the first child element of type `tag`.

```css
.foo {
border-collapse: collapse;
}

.foo tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1) {
background-color: green;
}

.foo tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(2) {
background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table class="foo">
  <tr><td>A</td><td>B</td></tr>
  <tr><td>C</td>
  <td>
     <table><tr><td>Not here...</td></tr></table>
  </td>
  </tr>
</div>
```

Comment: add `>` after the first selector maybe ?

Comment: probably `.foo > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) ... `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use direct descendant combinator  `>`
2. Find an ancestor higher up the tree `<div>`
3. Use `nth-of-type`

> ```
> div > table > tbody > tr:first-of-type > td:first-of-type
> ```
>
> ```css
> .foo {
>   border-collapse: collapse;
> }
>
> div>table>tbody>tr:first-of-type>td:first-of-type {
>   background-color: green;
> }
>
> .foo tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(2) {
>   background-color: red;
> }
> ```
>
> ```html
> <div>
>   <table class="foo">
>     <tr>
>       <td>A</td>
>       <td>B</td>
>     </tr>
>     <tr>
>       <td>C</td>
>       <td>
>         <table>
>           <tr>
>             <td>Not here...</td>
>           </tr>
>         </table>
>       </td>
>     </tr>
>   </table>
> </div>
> ```

Comment: In your solution you are getting rid of `tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1)`. I would like to consider the general case.

Comment: If you are using `nth` selectors then you shouldn't be concerned with general aspects and expect specific exclusions

Comment: Also this is a table with nested tables and `nth-child(1)` == `first-of-type` for all intents and purposes when dealing with table structures because a table must have a tbody as child, a tbody must have a tr as a child a tr must have a th or td as a child.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the style using another selector:

```css
.foo {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.foo tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: green;
}

.foo tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: red;
}

.foo table td:not(#random_id_for_specificity){
  all:initial; /*to override everything*/
}
```

```html
<table class="foo">
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Not here...</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is good, but I am not generic since I have to invalidate every single CSS rule. In my use case I have many other CSS rules `border, font-weight, ...`.

Comment: @nowox you can use `all:unset` (update my answer) but pay attention to browser support